# Select records from joint tables

Tags: sql, select, distinct

Got two tables:

```
tblJumper
  JumperID
  JumperName
```

and

```
tblWidthScored
  ScoreID
  fkJumperID
  fkScoredWidth
```

Tables related by `tblWidthScored.fkJumperID = tblJumper.JumperID`

Table Contains following data:

```
tblJumper
  1   Tom
  2   Jerry
  3   Bugs
tblWidthScored
  1   1   5,72m
  2   2   6,13m 
  3   1   5,80m 
  4   3   6,40m
  5   2   6,30m
  6   3   6,20m
```

What I'm trying to get is a list of each Jumpers personla best:

```
  Tom    5,80m
  Jerry  6,30m
  Bugs   6,40m
```

Tried SELECT DISTINCT... in various forms but didn't succeed in any way. 
Anyone couldl give a hint, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I think this is just a Join question and appropriate articles could be found on the web, I'll post one of the answers...

```
 SELECT
  J.JumperName,
  S.Score
 FROM tblJumper as J
   INNER JOIN(
               SELECT
                 fkJumperID, 
                 Max(fkScoredWidth) as Score 
               FROM tblWidthScored 
               GROUP BY
                 fkJumperID
             ) as S on J.JumperID = S.fkJumperID
```

The hints you're asking for are in your actual question actually:

You're trying to find personal bests! That means some kind of aggregation: `Maximum`.

You're trying to find personal bests distinctly. Not "the best score amongst whole jumpers" but every person's personal best distinctly. That means some kind of distinction or grouping that you can partition the score datas people by people: `Group By Clause`

Comment: Thanks for your help - and the details about how to find it. Didn't think about "group by" so didn't even look in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy if i'd been helpful ;) I'm takin' away my downvote since you provided feedback and did some research (i guess :)) and the downvote was for that; and kindly asking you to accept one of these answers as the correct one. Since we all take same approaches and gave same answers, you can just pick one of these; it isn't matter, 'cause the correct one was the `Group By`

Comment: Hello, The_aLiEn!   So - if you felt you wanted to "downvote" me - what ever that means - why not be a man and stick to it.  I _had_ done reseach for quite a time - as you stated in your wonderful explanation:  it was all in my question. From your Picture I might say I started with dBase and sql even before you were Born and something was lost in the decades passed. I didn't even look in the right direction.  You did a great Job pointing out how to get to the answer. Perhaps you might consider that someone asking a question at Christmas (it's all in the date of my question - at 1:20 am!) ...

Comment: ... might not just have gotten up from a delicious meal thinking how to upset hard working supporters with a silly question  :-)   For decades now of nine customers calling in "my Printer doesn't print" get it back working by re-plugging the power-supply that fell off during some celaning of the room. It's like that. So - again: you're a fine teacher - You may keep my "demerits" and be more patient with the next guy asking for help after hours and hours, days and days of fruitless Research, just because he Looks in the wrong direction and has no one to ask at the next desk. I for my part leave

Comment: Downvote means that i gave a minus one to your question, since it kind of deserved the lack of research it showed, not it could have inclueded some. And i think, it's not a manhood thing that i'd stick to it or not, it is what this community works on.. You downvote the questions and answers they don't deserve an up one. When you, sir, provided a feed back after two and a half month, i think i was polite enough to be honest and straight out to say i took it back and gave an up one, even it was a question with an unaccepted answer; it is what this community operates on: ...

Comment: ... valueable questions side by side valuable answers :) And check my profile, i've got plenty of down ones :) Which make me to improve myself on things i don't know enough (take, mr. haffernan pointed me to various things, for that matter). From my picture, you should not judge to get a conclusion using the age difference between us, because, i'm in this bussiness, in various parts of it, over 20 years now :) And I always envy and respect and honor the knowledge of you elders of me. I apologise if any lines were crossed ;)

Comment: And, sir, it was a group by, c'mon :p I do also hate "my Printer doesn't print" people :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query. for this type of query, you have to use Group BY Clause with Sub-query.

```
 SELECT JumperName, innertblWidthScored
 FROM tblJumper INNER JOIN(SELECT fkJumperID, 
               Max(fkScoredWidth) as innertblWidthScored
               FROM tblWidthScored 
               GROUP BY fkJumperID) WidthScored 
 on tblJumper.JumperID = WidthScored.fkJumperID
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74ac5/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could as well start with the `JOIN`, and do the `GROUP BY` afterwards. And if your sample output does actually suggest a sort order, you need an `ORDER BY`, too.

```
SELECT
  JumperName
  , MAX(fkScoredWidth) PersonalBest
FROM tblJumper
JOIN tblWidthScored
  ON JumperID = fkJumperID
GROUP BY JumperName
ORDER BY MAX(fkScoredWidth) DESC;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/becfa/4/0)

Comment: It was the Group By I didn't think of. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From result it seems that you want to retrieve jumper with its best score

try this -

```
select
  a.jumperName,
  b.bestScore
from tblJumper a, (
                    select
                      max(fkScoredWidth) as bestScore,
                      fkJumperID
                    from tblWidthScored
                    group by
                      fkJumperID
                  ) b on b.fkJumperID = a.JumperID
order by
  a.JumperID
```